# Laravel Job Mail files failed to open the file

Tags: laravel

I wanted to add a job to send a mail to a big list of adresses; but i get an exception

> Swift_IoException: Unable to open file for reading

I method was working perfectly without the job but now when i use a dispatch job with database i get this error. someone knows why i get the exception ?

When i use this directly in the controller the attachement work :

```
if($request->uploads){

            foreach($request->uploads as $file) {
                $files[] = [
                    'file' => $file->getRealPath(),
                    'options' => [
                        'mime' => $file->getClientMimeType(),
                        'as'    => $file->getClientOriginalName()
                    ],
                ];
            }

        }else{

            $files = null;

        }

    Mail::to($emails)->send(new MassiveEmail($subject , $bodyMessage , $files));
```

But when i use this, it's doesn't work :

```
$job = (new SendEmailMassiveJob($emails , $subject , $bodyMessage , $files))
            ->delay(Carbon::now()->addSeconds(10));

        dispatch($job);
```

Here my job class :

```
public function handle()
    {

        $emails = $this->emails;
        $subject = $this->subject;
        $bodyMessage = $this->bodyMessage;
        $files = $this->files;

        foreach ($emails as $email){

            Mail::to($email)->send(new MassiveEmail($subject , $bodyMessage , $files));

        }
    }
```

Here my mail class who generate an error when i attach the files:

```
public function build()
    {

        $subject = $this->subject;
        $bodyMessage = $this->bodyMessage;
        $files = $this->files;

        $email =  $this->markdown('email.MassiveMail',compact('bodyMessage'))
            ->subject($subject.'-'.'FFRXIII Licences & Compétitions');

        if($files){

            foreach($files as $file) {
                $email->attach($file['file'],$file['options']);
            }

        }

        return $email;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to run the task in 'sync' mode? Does the queue worker run on the same server where the files are uploaded? To me it looks like the file path can't be found when the worker tries to process it.

Comment: i try with sync mode now ! but with sync mode i can't delay to process. i work in local env actually

Comment: Yeah, the sync mode suggestion was just a debugging tip really, to see if the problem is related to the uploaded file location not being accessible/found by the queue worker process. Another thing you can try is to move the file to a location where you're sure it can be accessed by the worker before you fire the task, and pass the new path to the task

Comment: in which directory i can move it ? because actually i don't store the files i just send them by mail without storing.